# How to use BEGIN function in a trigger function in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm using POSTGRESQL-10 and trying to make a TRIGGER function.

I followed the example in this tutorial *http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/ *
So I created a table :

```
CREATE TABLE employee_audits (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   employee_id INT NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   changed_on TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
)
```

Then I wanted to create the followed trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_last_name_changes()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.last_name <> OLD.last_name THEN
       INSERT INTO employee_audits(employee_id,last_name,changed_on)
       VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name,now());
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
```

However when I tried to execute this function, PostgreSQL returned me an synthax error because of the BEGIN.

By any chance, could anybody help me to find out the problems please ?

Comment: I have tried and there is no issue just Add language plpgsql after closing body..

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? An what exactly do you mean with "executing" the function?

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the required `LANGUAGE` clause from the function you quoted, but odds are that you said

```
LANGUAGE sql
```

rather than

```
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The language validator of the procedural language you specified does not recognize the `BEGIN` at the beginning of the function body.